# Automation Task in Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I am working on a c++ solution which contains 20 projects. My first project builds and I run it as a pre-build event for rest of the projects. Now this executable actually creates some c++ files which should get added to all the other projects which are yet to be compiled. How should I do this? (Using VS2008)

Here are few solutions I thought.

Solution 1:

Let the exe update the vcproj file for all the remaining projects. But in this case as the project is on in VS, it creates some reload popup which I dont want.  So is there any way to suppress this popup and just save the changes.

Solution 2:

Visual Automation:

I was just going through some automation API.

The solution and project interface methods would help in adding new file. But will it not create a new pop up as the previous on?  Can I use MSbuild here?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Generated_*.cpp` (or similar pattern) as name of items for corresponding group in project. Than when project is build it will pick up all matching files, even once generated during pre-build steps.

If number of files is small you can just add them to the project directly (which I believe is ok even if they are missing before build).

Note that it may be good idea to generate files into separate folder (like `obj\....`) so you don't run into cases when someone mistakenly checks in generated files.

Comment: I can only have a pattern like *.cpp. And I cannot add them in the project manually. And how do we specify like build all the files in the folder with *.cpp pattern?. I guess we have to somehow make it add to the vcproj file so that it gets build.